# Preloading UITableView cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView which retrieves some data from a database which is relatively expensive to prefetch. To combat this problem I have used the design ideas from the [LazyTableImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code to fetch data for visible rows when a scroll ends by using `[UITableView visibleCells]`.

This works well in terms of performance, but it has two interaction problems i'd like to solve:

1. The data isn't loaded until a scroll has come to a complete halt (i.e. `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`). So if I scroll slowly through a list I have to stop the scroll to get the data to load into those visible cells. Ideally if the scroll was going at a slow speed i'd load the data into the cells.
2. I'd like to prefetch maybe the 1 or two table cells data which are just off screen in anticipation of scrolling to them.

Is there a an elegant way to achieve this?
I get the feeling I might be missing a common design pattern for this problem.

Comment: You should optimize prefetch.

Comment: An approach i've tried is to preLoad cells 30 at a time, but if the user scrolls too quickly then I end up will cells which don't have data in place and then don't load.

Comment: Load the content of the UITableViewCell asynchrony in a custom subclass of UITableView. When loading completed replace the placeholder text by going back to the main thread. So the main thread (which handles the UI stuff) won't be blocked too long and it will allow smooth scrolling.

Answer (score 6):

I think you can start loading data when scrolling starts, so that you don't have to wait for scrolling to end. You can use one of these two methods:

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{}
```

And also you can always get the indexes of visible cells so I think you should be able to load a couple of more data instead of just the visible cells.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the LazyTableImages code as is, that's normal.
The loading is deferred until the scroll is ended.
In my test app (a simple instagram-like stream) I use a different approach: basically I subclass the cell, start the download from the cell itself, use the cell as a delegate of my download manager and then update the UI of the cell when the download is finished

In detail

- I start the download in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method (the LazyTableImages deferres the download if the view is scrolling, I don't because for me it's ok to load while scrolling) calling a "startDownload" method of my cell.
- My cell subclass is set as the delegate of my download manager, and when the download is complete the cell changes the placeholder with the real image (this is done in a custom "downloadManagerDidFinishDownloadForImage:(UIImage*)image" delegate method, implemented in the cell subclass)
- in my cell subclass I override the prepareForReuse method. Here, I can choose to stop the download if the cell is going to be reused. In my case, I simply unset the delegate and leave the download continue, because I have some image caching made with core data and I want the caching to continue.

Moreover, you have to take care of two things:

- your download manager need to work in background thread
- be sure to update your cell UI in the main thread. You can use

:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //update here your cell UI
});
```

in the delegate method (if that method is called by your download manager, it's sure called in a background thread, so you have to "move" in the main thread" using a dispatch).

If you want you can look my example, but it's "as is" (it's a test app and there is a lot of spaghetti code and things unrelated to your question ;-)

http://www.lombax.it/documents/InstaXplore.zip

In my example you have to look at:

- BrowseCell <-- the cell subclass
- BrowsePhotoViewController <-- the tableviewcontroller

other things are related to core data storage and instagram, but basically

- in cellForRowAtIndexPath I create a new cell (or reuse a previous one) and pass an InstaImage item (my custom image)
- the InstaImage check if a cached copy exists and if not, start download, then alert back the cell

you have a clear cache button to try again and again :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
// called on finger up if the user dragged. decelerate is true if it will continue moving afterwards
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate;



(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if (!decelerate)
    {
        //fetch data for visible rows
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the example from LazyTableImages, as mentioned it leaves cells 'unloaded' until the are on screen. I'd like it preloaded.

Answer (score 1):

If I didn't misunderstand your question, I think you can use this. You do load at the time *SOME* cell was displayed.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lazy Image logic is a great solution that i used to use in my tableviews but lately i had been implementing different solutions for the UITableViews. The first is implement NSOperation Queues like the ones in this video provided by Apple in the WWWDC https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?include=211#211

or you can try creating an infinite scroll that when you reach some uitableviewcell you will load a new "page" with more data, if you need some help with this solution, let me know!

hope this helps!

best regards,

Jorge.